# Is a computer with multi-architecture possible?

Tags: architecture, x86, arm, processor

I just wondering if there is a computer, containing 2 physical processors, each with different architecture. Maybe the goal is to achieve a computer which takes the advantages of both architecture.

Comment: There are some early prototypes of x86/ARM hybrid PC: http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Computicator-x86-CoreDuo-ARM-AIO,11277.html. Also there is a new Big.Little initiative from ARM to have two kinds of ARM cores (different microarchitecture) in single chip. Big is for fast high-performance ARM cores and Little for smaller and simpler energy-efficient cores. It is possible to switch between them dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not only possible but is quite real. A common PC with a graphics card is an example of such an architecture. The CPU runs the OS and other applications on top of it, while the GPU is used for tasks it's better at, like massively parallel computations. Some applications, like recent versions of Photoshop separate the computational load between the CPU and the GPU.

Comment: Yes. I think this is what I am looking for...

Comment: @gh10 glad i could help. If your question as answered, you could mark the answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 3):

PS3 is an actual example of such: the Cell processor has one PowerPC core (PPE) and six "Synergistic Processing Units" (SPU) with a completely different architecture optimized for SIMD/vector processing. Nintendo Wii and WiiU also combine two architectures: PowerPC and ARM.

Modern PC motherboards often (always?) have multiple processors besides the main CPU. For example, laptops invariably include an Embedded Controller (EC) - usually a 8051 core. But even on desktops, Intel chipsets embed a Management Engine (ME) with an ARC core while AMD 800 series chipset includes two 8051s. Then there are various peripherals such as WiFi controllers, network cards, video cards, USB controllers, RAID controllers and so on which also have a CPU inside (with the exception of video cards, these are most often ARM based, though MIPS is also common in network cards). Same about HDDs, keyboards and mice. CPUs are everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of motherboards allowing something like this.
I think there will be problem with launching programs (one will have to specify on which architecture application will run).